# Hosting application on Windows Azure VM using IIS using VSTS (Visual Studio Team System)

Tags: azure, iis, automation, azure-devops, devops

I want to host a .Net application on azure VM using IIS. I know the basics of Windows azure like creating a VM & other things.

I want to automate this whole process of creating a VM & hosting an application on IIS on that VM using VSTS (Visual Studio Team System). I know its possible to do it using VSTS (DevOps) also I know basics of VSTS like creating a build definition on it, but I am facing problems in automating my current scenario using DevOps on azure.

All I want to know is how to initiate things like creating VM & installing IIS & hosting application on it automatically using VSTS build steps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could go about creating a VM with IIS+App in Azure. To create resources in Azure in an automated workflow, I usually think of using Azure Resource Manager Templates for the configuration.  To do that in VSTS, you can take a look at this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-ci-in-vsts

There are two ways to use AzureRM templates in VSTS build/release tasks, both are doc'd there.  The doc shows how to use an Azure Resource Group project in VSTS, but you could also just pull raw files from github (no project needed).

For a template that creates a VM, installs IIS and installs a web deploy package take a look at this sample:

https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples/tree/master/VMDSCWebDeploy

This uses DSC to install IIS, install and start web deploy and deploy a package/app.  That will do everything in the DSC script, but you could separate deployment if you wanted to.

That help?